# Get a single array from mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get all of the values in a certain field in a table. The basic query:

```
SELECT `field`
FROM `table`
WHERE `category`="something"
ORDER BY `other_field` DESC
```

The names of these fields will be return to an AJAX call, so my idea right now is to get this information into an array, and then `json_encode` that array.

But it's just a list of names, and it's ending up in JavaScript. And my "array/encode" method would require going over the results twice (when the query returns, I'd have to convert a two-dimensional array to one-dimensional). I'd like to avoid that, if possible.

So is there a better method to do this that I don't see? Is there MySQL function that will return all the `field`s as a single array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get all `field` values in one row, then convert it to array by `explode` in php. I'm not sure if it is faster than iterating over collection though.
**Update** A short query example.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`field` ORDER BY `order_field` DESC SEPARATOR '|')
FROM `table`
WHERE `category`="something";
```

*Notice : while choosing separator, make sure it doesn't occur in `field`'s values. It's also possible to escape occurrences of separator in `field` using, for instance, [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Now I can just echo the `GROUP_CONCAT` straight to JavaScript, and split it there. Thanks.

Comment: @alex please write UPDATED Query..it will b helpful for seeker